# How to properly extend some Javascript object function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to create a Postbox addon (Postbox is a mail client based on Thunderbird) and I'm having a small problem. I'm far from being a Javascript expert and I can't understand the problem behind this...

I'm trying to extend some object function from the Postbox code. The code is quite big, so I tried to create a small example to demonstrate my problem. The following code is a sample of the original Postbox code structure:

```
FolderTreeView.prototype = {

    init: function FTV__init() {
        alert("init");
    },

    _ensureValidRow: function FTV__ensureValidRow(aRow) {
        alert("_ensureValidRow");
    },

    getCellProperties: function FTV_getCellProperties(aRow, aColumn, aProperties) {
        this._ensureValidRow(aRow);
    }

}

function FolderTreeView() {
    this._tree = null;
    this.init();
}

var gFolderView = new FolderTreeView();
```

I cannot change this code cause when Postbox gets updated, the code would revert to the original source and it would be a pain to maintain that.

The following is my own code, trying to extend the `getCellProperties` function:

```
MyExtension = {

    init: function() {
        MyExtension.FolderIcon.load();
    },

    FolderIcon: {
        load: function() {
            var oGetCellProperties = gFolderView.getCellProperties;

            gFolderView.getCellProperties = function FTV_getCellProperties(aRow, aColumn, aProperties) {
                oGetCellProperties(aRow, aColumn, aProperties);
            }

            gFolderView.getCellProperties(null, null, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, `oGetCellProperties` is calling the original function, which in turn tries to call `this._ensureValidRow` but it fails. The error console reports that:

```
this._ensureValidRow is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.b()` sets the `this` value inside `b` to `a`. Saving it does not:

```
a.b(); // sets `this` value inside `b` to `a`

var c = a.b;

c(); // does *not* set `this` value inside `b` to `a`
```

So where you have:

```
var oGetCellProperties = gFolderView.getCellProperties;
// gFolderView is lost as `this` value
```

You rather want `.bind`. `.bind` is only available in newer browsers, but there are [shims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for older browsers.

```
var oGetCellProperties = gFolderView.getCellProperties.bind(gFolderView);
// force `this` value
```

Or you can set the `this` value each time you call, using `.call`:

```
//                      `this`       argument1, ...
oGetCellProperties.call(gFolderView, aRow,      aColumn, aProperties);
```

Comment: This is a great answer; I love the ES5 additions, but OP might want to check this table to see if his target browser(s) are supported. http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: This is not to run on a browser per se, it's a Postbox/Thunderbird extension. I just tested the `bind` and `call` methods in the extension and both worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that functions invoke with `function invocation`—some function just being called, as opposed to being invoke on an object

```
someFunction();
```

always, **always** set `this` to the global object.  You can get around this by invoking the function with `call`, which allows you to specify what you want `this` to be equal to

```
gFolderView.getCellProperties = function FTV_getCellProperties(aRow, aColumn, aProperties) {
       oGetCellProperties.call(gFolderView, aRow, aColumn, aProperties);
}
```

`apply` would work too, but it expects its arguments to be passed as an array, which is slightly less convenient in your case.

```
gFolderView.getCellProperties = function FTV_getCellProperties(aRow, aColumn, aProperties) {
       oGetCellProperties.apply(gFolderView, [aRow, aColumn, aProperties]);
}
```